# Removing duplicate values from SplDoublyLinkedList

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a method to remove duplicate values from a list? I was trying to create my own method, but it takes quite a lot time depending on how much there is duplicate values:

```
$arr = new SplDoublyLinkedList();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    for ($j = $i; $j < count($arr); $j++) {
        if ($arr[$i] == $arr[$j] && $i != $j) {
            $arr->offsetUnset($j);
            $j -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

E.g. if there is a 4000 items and about 1000 unique items on a list, it takes about 7 seconds to remove these items.

Comment: You could keep a set of “seen” items to do it in place, but I’d just use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique).

Comment: Your method is O(x²), you can gain time with quicksort or other algorithm method.